# SQL Query that fetches all rows in which

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch all the rows that have a certain value within one multiple-valued field. I think it's easier to express in an example:

```
Table Cars:

Car_Brand : Toyota
Available_Colors: green, blue

Car_Brand : Ferrari
Available_Colors: blue

Car_Brand : Dodge
Available_Colors: green

Car_Brand : Kia
Available_Colors: pink, blue
```

So my table is Cars and each row has only 2 fields. The first one "Car_Brand" is a simple string field. The second field is a multiple-valued field generated with multiple-select input.

I want to do 2 things:

1. fetch all cars that are avaiable in blue.
2. fetch all cars that are available in blue and green.

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Available_Colors IN ('blue');
```

fetched only Ferrary (without KIA or TOYOTA).

That's all the functionality I've managed to achieve so far. I've looked a lot but all I could find was using the IN operator to get a lot of rows that had different single valued field (WHERE country IN ('Germany', 'Japan')) so any help would be quite appreciated...

**EDIT:**

I am working with an opensource project (vTiger) so I am not at all building the database, but only working with fetching information from it or inputting data to it via the vTiger system. As so I have a rather limited knowledge of how the DB is actually structured.

However using the LIKE operator for my queries has solved the issue for my needs.

Comment: Storing values as csv  is **very bad** db design. Learn about normalization. On only Looks for `blue` as one word in the column `Available_Colors` not in a csv list

Comment: If you can't change the desing now, you can try SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Available_Colors LIKE '%blue%' OR Available_Colors  LIKE '%Green%';

Comment: Fix your database so you have another table called, say, `CarColors`, with one row per car and one row per color.

Comment: also for @Jens

(thankfully) I am not building the DB itself i'm only querying through it. So perhaps my misunderstanding of how the multiple-values are stored in it are the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's Very bad database design

You can try

**Query** : SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Available_Colors LIKE '%blue%'

**Other solution** :

Fix your database so you have another table called, say, **CarColors**, with one row per car and one row per color.